# Smart Plug that turns off when restarted?

Tags: smart-plugs

I am designing a simple control circuit.
I am turning on a motor using smart plug.
I am looking for a smart plug that shouldn't turn on automatically when power is cut off to it. Means it should turn on when I turn on the smart plug, and should stay on until I turn it off or power is lost to the plug.

The reason being is that, this circuit would be installed in a place where power is shut off frequently. And I don't want my motor to turn on every time power is back.

So, either the plug can go to off state whenever it is restarted, or If I can program that in smart plug?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: is the smart plug designed for use with a motor?

Comment: No, its a normal smart plug. I am using it to turn on a Contactor for the motor

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the sonoff range, most of there units are inline but it looks like they do sockets as well (https://sonoff.tech/product-category/wifi-smart-plugs).

There are opensource versions of the firmware for them which should allow you to control what happens when the system boots after the power goes out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge variety of smart plugs which contain the esp8266 chip.

The [Tasmota firmware](https://tasmota.github.io/docs/#/) is one very popular choice of custom firmware to flash to those devices. Tasmota offers a configuration option for the [power on behaviour](https://github.com/arendst/Tasmota/wiki/PowerOnState-Configuration#predefined-poweronstate-functionality).

Depending of the type of smart plug you choose, you either

- need to open the plug to access the necessary pins for flashing
- can update to Tasmota via exploiting an over-the-air firmware update weakness (google [Tuya-convert](https://github.com/ct-Open-Source/tuya-convert))
- or you can buy devices, which are already flashed with Tasmota

---

If you would like to use a smart plug, where the original manufacturer firmware already supports the feature you are looking for, I can recommend to look into the [Shelly smart plugs](https://shelly.cloud/shelly-plug-s/).